# Access a port in the command prompt by giving IP of the machine and port number?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, hyperterminal

I was looking everywhere to find a kind of alternative for `hyper terminal` such that i can use the feature like in the image here [`Hyper terminal screenshot`](http://www.acmesystems.it/old/53/hyperterminal.png)  in **`command prompt`**.  is this possible??

I am trying to replicate What exactly the hyperterminal does when we give the ip and the port number in its GUI in **`command prompt`**

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet might be what you are looking for.

This free tool is scriptable too:

Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0
by Albert Yale

Comment: I am trying to do exactly what a hyperterminal  or a telnet do as in command prompt...

Comment: a command prompt doesn't have modem or http or telnet access.  There are tools that allow access...  can you describe what you need to do?  Maybe someone can figure out a workaround.

Comment: How does these tools allow access? I hope all these will be in effect some commands.? please correct me if am wrong.?

Comment: Explain what you need to do.

Comment: Ok in simple i would like to access a port through IP. The reason why i don't need Hyper terminal is that some spaces or new lines are getting feeded at the end of the command, i tried disabling the option in the hyper terminal still its sending. I want to avoid this..